# jQuery datepicker not showing time but the date works

Tags: php, datepicker

my jquery datepicker shows date correctly but the time isn't working. the test result produces the following: 1372046400 = 2013-06-24 04:06:00

as you can see the time isnt same as the systemtime, it should be 8:19pm.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){    
                $("#date").datepicker({
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    minDate: '0M',
                    maxDate: '+90D',    
                    dateFormat: "d-MM-yy",  
                    onSelect : function(dateText, inst)
                    {   var epoch = $.datepicker.formatDate('@', $(this).datepicker('getDate')) / 1000;
                        $('#hidden1').val(epoch);
                    }
               });  
           });          

        </script>
```

php script that displays the output

```
$dateTime = $_POST['hidden1'];  
$date = new DateTime('@'.$dateTime);
echo $saveDate = $date->format('U = Y-m-d h:m:s');
```

Answer (score 4):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

it has to be

```
$date->format('U = "Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

m is for month

Comment: I tired your suggestion and still no change. the time never changes. i have a feeling it has something to do with the conversion but cant put my finger on it.

Answer (score 2):

set your time zone (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and then try to use the answer that Sanath has suggested.

Example:-

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```